# Geometry has too many edges (3265164 > 2000000) (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am attempting to apply an NDBI to a country boundary of the U.S but I keep getting the warning

> Layer 8: Layer error: Collection.geometry: Geometry has too many edges (3265164 > 2000000).

Here is a copy of my code below

```
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
var image = S2.filterBounds(USA)
    .filterDate('2020-02-01', '2020-04-01')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than', 5)
    .first()
    .clip(USA);
```

What can I do to fix the geometry issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using any geometry operation, such as `clip`, on a `FeatureCollection` (which I assume from the error that `USA` is), causes all of the collection's features' geometries to be unioned into one big geometry. That single geometry can often be too big to process.

The first thing to try is *not* clipping the image. Clipping an image does not make it cheaper to process, so you should only do it if you actually need the result to be clipped.

If you do need it clipped, then use [`clipToCollection()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-cliptocollection) instead of `clip()`, which is made just for this purpose.

Comment: I replaced the .Clip() with the .ClipToCollection() but still received the same error message as before.

Comment: same here, @Majorian420 did you manage to find a solution?